# ARIMA on multiple location hourly data for outlier detection

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, outliers, autoregressive-models

Trying to solve an issue for some time. I have a dataframe which consists of a

- date and time (around 1 year of hourly data)
- location (1000 different locations)
- traffic (outcome that I would like to forecast)

Bellow is an example of the data

```
date <- as.Date(c('2015-11-1','2015-11-1','2015-11-1', '2015-11-1','2015-11-1','2015-11-1', '2015-11-1','2015-11-1','2015-11-1'))
hour <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
location <- c('location 1','location 2','location 3', 'location 1','location 2','location 3', 'location 1','location 2','location 3')
traffic <- c(1, 1.1, 1, 2, 2.5, 2.3, 2.5, 2.7, 3.6)
df <- data.frame(date, hour, location, traffic)
```

I am trying for some time to make a time serie per location. Below what I have tried, but I am not getting the results that I am looking for

```
fitted_models = df %>% group_by(location, date, hour) %>% 
   do(model = ts(data=df, start = c(2015-11-1, 0), frequency=3) )
```

The aim is to remove the seasonality and run an ARIMA model to find outliers per location.

How could I create per location a separate time serie (ARIMA model)?

Thank you in advance.
Eric

Comment: maybe use stf decomposition to get the seasonality out and then fit an ARIMA on the remaining? also check if the frequency present in data using the fourier transform method. i remember hyndman posting in one of the earlier answers a snippet to do that.

Comment: Thank you Varun, I will check the options. I have heard regarding the stf, but not seen anything yet on fourier transformation.

Comment: stf should take a time serie, any hints on the time serie creation?